# Show Indeterminate Indicator when loading another Activity

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm trying to show my `Indeterminate Progress Indicator` When a certain Card is being tapped.

I declared the indicator in my onCreate as follows

```
mSlider = Slider.from(mCardScroller);
mIndeterminate = mSlider.startIndeterminate();
```

Then in my onclick I have the following

```
mIndeterminate.show();
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CaptureActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

I want to show the progress indicator while the QR-Scan activity is being loaded since this takes a few seconds.

However with this the indicator doesn't show up at all. Is there a way to make sure the indicator is being shown while the called upon activity is loading?

When I take out the `startActivityForResult()` it does start the indicator so I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the lifecycle of the activity, but I'm not sure how I should go about it in this case.

Comment: Do you mean the transition from your current activity to CaptureActivity takes a few seconds?

Comment: @EntryLevelDev Yes that is exactly what I mean

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should put the slider in CaptureActivity instead.

Your slider is hidden. From my understanding, you start the progress bar in the activity which is moved to the background. The whole activity cannot be seen not only the progress bar.

Try moving these code into onCreate of CaptureActivity

```
mSlider = Slider.from(mCardScroller);
mIndeterminate = mSlider.startIndeterminate();
mIndeterminate.show();
```

Comment: This is a interesting one. I added that piece of code to my `CaptureActivity` I left the code in my other Activity as well. Now it started as soon as I tapped my card. I then went on and played around with it some more. eventually I ended up with commenting out the `mIndeterminate.show();` in the `CaptureActivity` class and it still works.  it seems to me that the decleration of the slider was needed in the activity that is being called to continue showing. In my oncreate in the CaptureActivity class I have a handler that stops the slider and it works perfect like this. Lil sketchy to me tho.

Comment: that's weird but glad to here that something's working.